# Separate numbers and [] data in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data in one of the column looks like this ALAN, DONALD[1234], I need to split this into two columns like Name( ALAN,DONALD), ID (1234)
I tried the following code and I was able to get the ID but not the name

```
create table  #test(NAME_ID VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO  #TEST VALUES ('ALAN,DONALD [1234])' )

SELECT CAST (substring(NAME_ID,charindex('[',NAME_ID)+1,charindex(']',NAME_ID)-charindex('[',NAME_ID)-1) AS VARCHAR (102) ) AS MRN FROM #TEST
```

Comment: Hint...use LEFT and CHARINDEX.

Comment: you should consider putting that code in a user defined table valued function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it based on the index of the bracket:

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM(SUBSTRING(NAME_ID, 0, CHARINDEX('[',NAME_ID))) AS Name,
    CAST (SUBSTRING(NAME_ID,CHARINDEX('[',NAME_ID)+1,CHARINDEX(']',NAME_ID)- 
    CHARINDEX('[',NAME_ID)-1) AS VARCHAR (102) ) AS MRN 
FROM #TEST
```